# Verificar página e atribuir DIV

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho 10 páginas, uma parte do layout é igual em 9 delas, então eu farei um `include` para poupar meu trabalho de repetir isso 9 vezes.

O que acontece, é que gostaria de usar esse `include` em todas as páginas, e quando essa parte do layout fosse diferente das outras, eu fizesse algum tipo de validação e mudasse o CSS ou o que for necessário.

Por exemplo, se eu estiver na página www.teste.com.br/produtos
dentro desse include, muda a div `teste1`, e nas outras 9 continua o padrão.

Não tenho código disso, pois ainda não comecei o projeto, gostaria de saber se alguém tem algum exemplo para que eu possa aproveitar.

Comment: Não dá para entender bem o problema. Você quer uma página que recebe dados via include? Você tem uma página "mãe" onde quer incluir um dos 10 arquivos de acordo com alguma condição? O que muda na página diferente é o estilo ou a estrutura do HTML? Você pretende fornecer algum tipo de identificador para saber em qual das 10 páginas está?

Comment: Obtem a parte que te interessa do URL com PHP, e faz a condição com isso

Comment: @EnoqueDuarte então, você teria algum exemplo de como criar essa condição?

Comment: <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "paginaxpto") { print "o meu html"; } ?>

Comment: @FelipeStoker, explicando melhor minha dúvida para poder lhe dar um exemplo adequado: por que fazer 9+1 páginas que chamam o mesmo layout, se você pode fazer uma com o tal layout e alterar apenas os dados que irão nela? Se são 10 páginas, não haveria por que fazer 10 includes, bastaria copiar o layout para cada uma delas e pronto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente seria melhor usar um arquivo template carregando o conteúdo por meio de parâmetros na URL, mas se você esta acostumado com essa estrutura, e/ou prefere que a URL fique com os nomes dos arquivos simplesmente, segue um pequeno exemplo:

**contato.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
include('menu.php');
?>

<div class="conteudo">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget varius urna. Quisque convallis augue quis magna consequat eleifend. Nulla posuere sit amet lectus sed porta. Ut quis mauris luctus, lobortis ligula et, interdum massa. Praesent varius tempor laoreet. Vestibulum vulputate massa vel nunc vulputate, ut pellentesque massa rutrum. Aenean posuere, arcu eget eleifend auctor, diam lorem volutpat massa, vel commodo quam urna a mauris.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**menu.php**

```
<?php
$pagina_atual = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

if ($pagina_atual == 'contato.php') {
    echo '<script src="js/contato.js"></script>';
}

?>
<ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
     <li<?php echo ($pagina_atual == 'index.php' ? ' class="ativo"' : ''); ?>>
         <a href="index.php">Início</a>
     </li>
     <li<?php echo ($pagina_atual == 'sobre.php' ? ' class="ativo"' : ''); ?>>
         <a href="sobre.php">Sobre</a>
     </li>
     <li<?php echo ($pagina_atual == 'contato.php' ? ' class="ativo"' : ''); ?>>
         <a href="contato.php">Contato</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

como você pode ver, apenas quando a pagina for *contato.php* é que vai incluir o `<script src="js/contato.js"></script>` e de bônus foi um exemplo de como aplicar a classe ativo no menu.